# Unexpected EOF While Parsing with 2 lines of Code

Tags: python-3.x

[image: My Code]

I am wondering exactly what is wrong with my code and what would cause such an error

Comment: Missing bracket for print. For future questions, please use actual code blocks rather than images of code, as these can then be copied, run, analysed etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an extra `)` on the end of the second line :)